# Purple line on left side of screen when I use graphics card's hdmi port

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hdmi

My graphics card is a nVidia GeForce GTX 660 2GB.

When I plug HDMI into mobo it works fine. When I plug it into the graphics card (with 2nd monitor too) it shows a purple vertical line on the left side. It adds 2 pixels to the width and I can't adjust it with my monitor. It doesn't come up when I print screen.

I tried changing the driver to the binary one (at the top) but that made it not show up at all.

What do I do? Are some graphics cards just not compatible?

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with GTX 760 only when I use nouveau driver. It is a real problem, as i may see =(

About binary driver: Black screen in the VT may be caused because of unsolved issues related to EFI (on nvidia side), or if you are talking about "Xorg black screen" - this is all because you didn't configured xorg.conf.

I can't explain you how you have to configure your xorg.conf because.. well.. I'm not ubuntu user.
Good luck!

Comment: I have the same problem as well, only with nouveau.